# django form.is_valid returns false for unicode filename

Tags: python, django, forms, encoding, unicode

Using the django web framework, I'm trying to upload a video file. Therefor, my model has a FileField called videoFile, for which I use the default form field.
Uploading videos works just fine, as long as the filename does not contain non-ascii characters.

If it does, the form.is_valid() method returns false.
form.errors says: 
"videoFile, This field is required."

I set `request.encoding = 'utf-8'` before filling the form and trying to validate it.

Does anyone know how to make is_valid() accept unicode filenames for FileFields?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

The server runs Debian 3.2.46-1, however, my development machine with openSUSE 12.3 shows the same behavior.

In /etc/apache2/envvars

```
export LANG='en_US.UTF-8'
export LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8'
export LC_LANG='en_US.UTF-8'
```

is set.

Comment: Not sure if helpful but there might be a solution here; [Django UnicodeEncodeError when uploading files](http://tech.barszcz.info/2012/05/17/django-unicodeencodeerror-when-uploading-files/).

Comment: What operating system are you using?